# Show that the given function is a uniformly continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $F : \mathbb{R}^{n} → \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$F(x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n) = \max\{|x_1|, |x_2|, . . . , |x_n|\}$.
Show that $F$ is a uniformly continuous function.

I really have nothing to show as to what I have tried.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. The triangle inequality on $\def\R{\mathbf R}\R$ gives $|x_i + y_i| \le |x_i| + |y_i|$. Hence, 
$$ F(x + y) \le F(x) + F(y) $$
So
$$ F(x) \le F(x-y) + F(y), \text{ and } F(y) \le F(x-y) + F(x) $$
giving
$$ |F(x) - F(y)| \le F(x-y) $$

Answer (score 2):

$||(x_1,...,x_n)||_{max} = \mathop{max}_{i: 1,...,n} |x_i|$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. So by the second triangle inequality:
$$\left| \:||(x_1,...,x_n)||_{max} -||(y_1,...,y_n)||_{max} \right| \leq ||(x_1,...x_n)-(y_1,...y_n)||_{max}$$
Hence $F$ is Lipschitz continuous (with respect to the $||.||_{max}$-norm) and from that is is uniformly continuous.